# Sorting problems in txt file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a [templates](http://our-templates.com)
website. I've a ready database in txt file. I know that ordering from bottom to top is possible using MySQL (ORDER BY `id` DESC), but I don't want to insert these files in database. I want them to be sorted from txt file from bottom to top, but don't know the appropriate PHP code. I've heard it's something like sort() or usort(). A little help will be appreciated!

thanks in advance!

Comment: have you Googled for php sort() function?

Comment: yes but it didn't work!

Comment: This question is ok for google, not for SO. Show us what you tried and why didn't work.

Comment: get the text with file(), set it to a variable, and use sort()

Comment: I tried sorting txt file like this:

$conts = file_get_contents("base.txt");

sort($conts);

Comment: `where customers can buy templates` ... hire developers

Comment: @SandroV `sort()` sorts arrays - `file_get_contents` returns a string

Comment: A .txt file is not a database! Use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [sort()](https://www.php.net/sort)

`file()` reads a file into an array (each line becomes and element), then you can sort that array with `sort()`

Comment: That's what I've just said at comments.

Comment: I'll try it in just a moment!

Comment: @Arda Yea I spotted it once I submitted my answer. if you've got an answer, post an answer not a comment

Comment: It worked, I'll accept answer in minutes!

Comment: @SmokeyPHP for a "proper" answer, we'd require more info (like his code). Yours is a suggestion, not an answer. After all, you didn't code for him, just showed him the way.